# what's the Time Complexity and Auxiliary space for this method?

Tags: java, time-complexity, space-complexity

What's the time complexity and auxiliary space for this method? Can anyone please tell and explain me the results?

```
public Set<T> findRepeatedValues(List<T> list){
    Set<T> set = new HashSet<>();
    Set<T> repeatedValues = new HashSet<>();
    for (T i: list) {
        if (!set.add(i)) {
            repeatedValues.add(i);
        }
    }
    return repeatedValues;
}
```

what happened if I Test my code like below?

```
@Test
public void findRepeatedStrings(){
    List<String> stringList = new ArrayList<String>(Arrays.asList("ali","mahdi","hadi","mahdi","mojtaba","mohammad","mojtaba"));
    RepeatedValues repeatedValues = new RepeatedValues();
    Set values = repeatedValues.findRepeatedValues(stringList);
    for (Object i :
            values) {
        System.out.println(i);
    }
}
```

Comment: `!set.add(i)`! This means you will never enter the loop.

Comment: @TiMr not exactly, that would return `false` if the element already exists in `Set` and hence the `if `condition would hold `true` for repeated elements.

Comment: @nullpointee Thanks!!

Answer (score 1):

#### Time complexity

The time complexity of your code would be **`O(n)`** , *where `n` is the number of elements in the `list`*. Reason:

```
for (T i : list) { // iterates through all the 'n' elements
    if (!set.add(i)) {
        repeatedValues.add(i);
    }
}
```

#### Space complexity

On the other hand, since you're using a `Set` to temporarily store values, the space required in the worst case for your `Set` used would be:

```
Set<T> set = new HashSet<>(list.size()); // all elements are unique
```

Hence the space complexity of your solution would be **`O(n)`** as well. Of course, `n` is a value that as the size of the list. If the size of the list grows the space required grows as well.

#### Output

```
public void printRepeatedStrings(){
    List<String> stringList = Arrays.asList("ali","mahdi","hadi","mahdi","mojtaba","mohammad","mojtaba");
    RepeatedValues<String> repeatedValues = new RepeatedValues<>(); // type 'T' bound 
    repeatedValues.findRepeatedValues(stringList)
                  .forEach(System.out::println); // prints ["mahdi","mojtaba"]
}
```

Answer (score 0):

#### Complexity

- Time complexity is **O(n)**
- Space complexity is **O(n)**

#### Explanation

```
public Set<T> findRepeatedValues(List<T> list){
    // both sets contains n elements: hence space complexity is O(n)
    Set<T> set = new HashSet<>();
    Set<T> repeatedValues = new HashSet<>();

    // iterate over list only once: hence time complexity is O(n)
    for (T i: list) {
        // HashSet add has O(1) time complexity
        if (!set.add(i)) {
            repeatedValues.add(i);
        }
    }

    return repeatedValues;
}
```

#### Test

Your test is incorrect. You have to check that returned `Set` contains required data. It cold be look like:

```
public static void findRepeatedStrings() {
    List<String> list = Arrays.asList("ali", "mahdi", "hadi", "mahdi", "mojtaba", "mohammad", "mojtaba");
    Set<String> values = new RepeatedValues<String>().findRepeatedValues(list);

    MatcherAssert.assertThat(values, IsCollectionWithSize.hasSize(2));
    MatcherAssert.assertThat(values, IsIterableContainingInOrder.contains("mahdi", "mojtaba"));
}
```

Comment: "PS" Such a predicate is not "a non-interfering, stateless predicate", as required by [`filter`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/stream/Stream.html#filter-java.util.function.Predicate-) (it's very similar to the canonical example of a stateful lambda). This would not be guaranteed to work.